# Can I only accept traffic from certain requesting domains with Expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I would like to be able to only let requests from a very specific domain get successfully served by a node app I have on heroku.

The code I tried is

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.hostname === "example.com") {
    next();
    }
});
```

Turns out req.hostname seems to be the name of my heroku appserver... I've looked over the express docs for the `req` object but don't see anything else promising.

(I see IP is a possibility but the IP situation for where the traffic is coming from changes from time to time and I'm not in the loop on that.)

I feel like the domain of the request has to be somewhere... But maybe what I want isn't possible.

Comment: Browser traffic comes "from" a user's computer, not from a domain.  Not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Ok. I have some jQuery that is GETting json from this node app. And all the requests will come from a system on campus and I was hoping to lock down the app to only accept requests from that system

Comment: Why don't you just use some sort of password that you only share with that system?  What does "domain of request" mean?

Comment: It doesn't surprise me at all that I'm not using the terminology correctly, my bad. So, if my client-side code is on a page www.example.com/funstuff.html I would want to have express accept a request from example.com

Comment: Passwording won't work for this situation because the page is intended for public consumption. My node app is working with a 3rd party api and I was just wondering if I could keep their data more secure by only allowing requests from specific places. It's not a strict requirement but I thought it might be easy to do and worthwhile.

Comment: `accept a request from example.com` is where you have things goofed up.  That request isn't coming from example.com.  That request is coming from some individual computer who is displaying a web page that they got from example.com.  Anyone on the internet can load and run that same web page.  Authentication is typically how you limit who can access what.  You require the user to enter some form of credential.  You can limit access by client IP (with various limitations), but you've already indicated you don't think that will work.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`accept a request from example.com` is where you have things goofed up.  That request isn't coming from example.com.  That request is coming from some individual computer who is displaying a web page that they got from example.com.  Anyone on the internet can load and run that same web page.

Authentication is typically how you limit who can access what.  You require the user to enter some form of credential.  You can limit access by client IP (with various limitations), but you've already indicated you don't think that will work.

The usual schemes for limiting who can access your server's functionality are:

1. Use some sort of authentication scheme (require user to enter a credential to "log in").  This can be your own auth scheme or can piggy back on some other existing auth scheme.
2. Whitelist access to your server from only a specific client IP address or range of IP addresses.  This is not used very often because it has all sorts of limitations.

FYI, as long as your server does not allow cross origin requests (which it will not by default), then some other web site can't access your server via a browser (the browser will prevent it).  But, any script junkie or hacker still can.  Only authentication or IP filtering will prevent a hacker from accessing your service.