# Protecting POST route without password possible?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, paypal

Noob here working on first backend project.

What I’m trying to do...

1. Collect member data via my form (name, email)
2. User clicks paypal button to pay for membership
3. When payment approved by paypal, send post request with form data to my members endpoint to add new member

I now realize if I use postman to post to my members endpoint it works. So a malicious user could post data to my members endpoint regardless of paypals payment approval.

My understanding so far is that if my server allows CORS and I don’t password verify the user, anyone can post to that endpoint.

Is it possible to allow post requests only after payment approval without the use of a password?
I’m thinking of online stores that let you checkout without a password. How do they post the collected form data to their db without jeopardizing their post route?

Hope this wasn’t too vague. Pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I’m using node/express, but since it’s a general question I assume it doesn’t really matter..

These answers helped but still didn’t get me there.

[Protecting post routes NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722844/protecting-post-routes-nodejs)

[Can I only accept traffic from certain requesting domains with Expressjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428402/can-i-only-accept-traffic-from-certain-requesting-domains-with-expressjs)

Comment: this requires the use of a "workflow" or some trigger from paypal. Your workflow would need to poll paypal for approval, then continue to add a new member. this would NOT be a public API...and you should seriously consider adding some sort of auth to APIs like this. Not sure ab paypal's capabilities, but you may be able to trigger an API via some sort of webhook...then only restrict the CORS to allow a paypal origin.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers Jon.. much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So post / get request in general are functions of the browser and or server, I can create a simple html form and post to any URL I want to.. Now the question is, will it accept it or not.

When communicating between servers and web-services unless open to the public will use token based authentication to validate the request. So in terms of paypal, the typical flow would be.

(note, very oversimplification below and is just a sample of one such pattern)

1. User clicks paypal button from your site ( this will contain some type of paypal ID of sorts )
2. User is directed to paypal and after completing the transaction paypal redirects users back to your server with a token
3. your server reads the token ( sends API call to paypal with token to verify its valid, if success then process the post )

You can't prevent a user from posting data to a URL, however you can tell the server what to do if they do. So protecting your route from unauthorized post can be handled by sessions, tokens etc. For example, if you have a route on your server, lets call it user profile. This route first executes a check for the session, if its there keep processing, if its not, redirect the user.. Its really no different for callbacks / token auth.

Essentially, you will need to handle what the server does in your code because anyone can post to the endpoint.

To your other question about how companies handle guest checkouts, this can be done a few ways but one way is to create your own token, this token would be an encrypted string that may contain a cart ID, time etc.

When a user clicks 'checkout' the token is generated and passed to the server via a get or post request. From there your server decodes the token and if everything is correct processes the order otherwise it kicks it back.

Again, you see a lot of token based stuff here going on and that because there is an X factor in all of this.. the user.. We know who the server is but the user can be from anywhere and the user isn't a server so we need some way to maintain state between servers, hence tokens, encryption, JWT etc

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! That’s exactly what I was hoping for. Will look into paypals server integration. And maybe give JWT a try to protect my route.